# angular ui-select - update selected when updating choices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

So I have a pretty basic select that looks like this:

```
<ui-select theme="select2" search-enabled="false" ng-model="obj.myModel">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.value as item in choices">
        <span>
            {{item.name}}
        </span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Let's say the `choices` are defined as

```
$scope.choices = [
    {value: 'some_value_1', name: 'Default name'},
    {value: 'some_value_2', name: 'Default name 2'}
]
```

Now let's assume that the user has selected the item with value `some_value_1`. After that a server response comes in that updates the `choices` list with different names

```
$scope.choices = [
   {value: 'some_value_1', name: 'Real name'},
   {value: 'some_value_2', name: 'Real name 2'}
]
```

Notice that the value part that is saved in the model stays the same. The name in `<ui-select>` is still ***Default name*** when I would want it to change to *Real name*.

[plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/W3YfB1TQ0kBPMMxbP2eG?p=preview)

Is there a way to make the selected name correspond to updated choices?

Comment: The problem is that the value in obj.myModel never changes so the screen never updates. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but if you set obj.myModel = '' at the time the new choices are set, let a digest cycle happen, and then reset it to the value then the screen updates. You can do this using a setTimeout() after your choices change. There may be a way to hook into some event but I'm not sure off the top of my head

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[UI-Select not updating currently selected entry when list changes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1944)

Do you find a solution outside the library ui-select?

I have made a solution to correct this inside the library, because the "$select.selected" is not updated when the list of choices is changed,
in the codes, ui-select tends to use the last value when list is changed while item.value is the same.
solution 1.
the following codes explain what I said.

```
ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (inputValue) {
    // Keep original value for undefined and null
    if (isNil(inputValue)) {
        return inputValue;
    }

    var data = $select.parserResult && $select.parserResult.source (scope, { $select : {search:''}}), //Overwrite $search
    locals = {},
    result;
    if (data){
        var checkFnSingle = function(d){
            locals[$select.parserResult.itemName] = d;
            result = $select.parserResult.modelMapper(scope, locals);
            // FIX by aescot https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/2038
            return angular.equals(result, inputValue);
        };
        //If possible pass same object stored in $select.selected
        // here is the problem when list updated 
        if ($select.selected && checkFnSingle($select.selected)) {
             return $select.selected;
        }
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
             if (checkFnSingle(data[i])) return data[i];
        }
    }
    return inputValue;
});
```

fix: add a line `ctrl.selected = undefined;`

```
$scope.$watchCollection(ctrl.parserResult.source, function(items) {
                    if (items === undefined || items === null) {
                        // If the user specifies undefined or null => reset the collection
                        // Special case: items can be undefined if the user did not initialized the collection on the scope
                        // i.e $scope.addresses = [] is missing
                        ctrl.items = [];
                    } else {
                        if (!angular.isArray(items)) {
                            throw uiSelectMinErr('items', "Expected an array but got '{0}'.", items);
                        } else {
                            //Remove already selected items (ex: while searching)
                            //TODO Should add a test
                            ctrl.refreshItems(items);

                            //update the view value with fresh data from items, if there is a valid model value
                            if(angular.isDefined(ctrl.ngModel.$modelValue)) {
                                ctrl.ngModel.$modelValue = null; //Force scope model value and ngModel value to be out of sync to re-run formatters

                                // clear $select.selected to force update on $select.selected
                                ctrl.selected = undefined;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

solution 2 (theory):
create your directive and add it on  directive,
in your directive you need require 'uiSelect' to get the controller of 
and the access $select in your link function,
`link: function(scope, element, attrs, $select) {`
make "$elect.selected = undefined"  when your list is updated
you need to wrap it in a function bind to a service to open this function